# If $ f = O(g) $ and $ g \notin O(f)$ then $\theta (f) \le \theta (g)$

Tags: asymptotics

> If $ f = O(g) $ and $ g \notin O(f)$ then $\theta (f) \le \theta (g)$

I've tried to use the definition of $O$ to demonstrate why  $\theta (f) \le \theta (g)$  by using the contradiction method but I couldn't. I don't know how to  write  $g \notin O(f)$ by definition.

Comment: What do you mean by $g\not \in O(g)$? We clearly have $|g(x)|\leq 1|g(x)| \forall x$...

Comment: What are $\theta(f)$ and $\theta(g)$?